# How to use Phonegap Calendar

Tags: html, cordova, calendar, adt

found https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin#phonegap-build

can anyone guide me or provide sample code so that I will known if this is working?

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin#3-usage

Comment: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Calendar-DemoApp

Comment: I can't get the demo to work I keep getting blank when i run it?

used this instead and runs fine

http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/adding-calendar-events-phonegap-android-plugin/